# javafx programs for user validation. Add user program works great. Login program has runtime errors. Tried many solutions, need assistance please

Tags: javafx, text-files

Having problems getting the "Login" program to run properly. AddUser works great, Login does not and ends up not responding. I have tried many code changes to "Login" and feel I nearly had it but the best I got was the GUI to display the "Invalid Username or Password" error although both were proper. Need HELP please!!

Here is the code for AddUser.java which writes the selected username and password to a users.txt file:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;

public class AddUser extends Application {
private TextField tfUsername = new TextField();
private TextField tfPassword = new TextField();
private Button btAddUser = new Button("Add User");
private Button btClear = new Button("Clear");

@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Create UI
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(5);
    gridPane.setVgap(5);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(tfUsername, 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
    gridPane.add(tfPassword, 1, 1);
    gridPane.add(btAddUser, 1, 3);
    gridPane.add(btClear, 1, 3);

    // Set properties for UI
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    tfUsername.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    tfPassword.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

    GridPane.setHalignment(btAddUser, HPos.RIGHT);
    GridPane.setHalignment(btClear, HPos.LEFT);

    Text text = new Text(" ");
    text.setFont(Font.font("Copperplate Gothic Light", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 16));
    text.setFill(Color.BLUE);


    // Process events
    btAddUser.setOnAction(e -> {
    writeNewUser();
    text.setText("User " + tfUsername.getText()+ " Added!");
    });


    btClear.setOnAction(e -> {
        tfUsername.clear();
        tfPassword.clear();
        text.setText("  ");
    });

    VBox vbox = new VBox(2);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(text, gridPane);
    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 150);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Add User"); // Set title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
}

public void writeNewUser() {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt", true))) {
        bw.write(tfUsername.getText()+"|"+tfPassword.getText());
        bw.newLine();

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
 * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Now, here is the "Login" program's code, this is where I'm having trouble.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.HPos;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
    import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Login extends Application {
     private TextField tfUser = new TextField();
     private PasswordField tfPass = new PasswordField();
     private Button btLogin = new Button("Login");
     private Button btClear = new Button("Clear");


@SuppressWarnings("resource")
@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Create UI
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(5);
    gridPane.setVgap(5);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(tfUser, 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
    gridPane.add(tfPass, 1, 1);
    gridPane.add(btLogin, 1, 3);
    gridPane.add(btClear, 1, 3);

    // Set properties for UI
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    tfUser.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    tfPass.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

    GridPane.setHalignment(btLogin, HPos.RIGHT);
    GridPane.setHalignment(btClear, HPos.LEFT);

    Text text = new Text();
    text.setFont(Font.font("Copperplate Gothic Light", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 16));


    // Process events
    btClear.setOnAction(e ->
   {
        tfUser.clear();
        tfPass.clear();
        text.setText("");
    });


    btLogin.setOnAction(e -> {
        boolean grantAccess = false;
        String userName = tfUser.getText();
        String password = tfPass.getText();

        File f = new File("users.txt");
        try {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(f);
        int noOfLines=0;
        while(read.hasNextLine()) {
           noOfLines++;

        }

        for(int i=0; i<noOfLines; i++) {
            if (read.nextLine().equals(userName)) {
                i++;
                if (read.nextLine().equals(password)) {
                 grantAccess=true;
                 break;
                }
            }
        }

    if(grantAccess) {
        text.setText("Welcome!");
        text.setFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
    }
    else {text.setText("Invalid Username or Password!");
    text.setFill(Color.RED);
    }
    }
     catch(FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
});

    VBox vbox = new VBox(2);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(text, gridPane);

      // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 150);
    primaryStage.setTitle("LOGIN"); // Set title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
}


/**
 * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
 * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Any Help Is Greatly Appreciated!!!! Thank you!

Comment: Doesn’t this just throw an exception? Your `while` loop reads lines until there are no more lines to read, and then you immediately try to read more lines...

Comment: Also the way try to encode the data does not match the way you decode it. You write a single line to the file containing both username and password separated by `|`; You decode the data by reading 2 separate lines. There's more of an issue with the way you read the code though: Imagine user A has password B and user B password C. B tries to log in with password C.Your code reads the first line and realizes that it does not match the username and goes to the next iteration of the loop.It then reads the line containing B,which matches the user name provided.The line read&compared to the pwd is B

Comment: The way you currently encode passwords also has issues. Let's say a user chooses the name `A|B` and password `C`. This results in the line encoded as `A|B|C`. How do you tell this appart from the user `A` with password `B|C`?

Comment: The adduser program adds the username and password separated by |, (A|B) —> (username|password). I know I have to make the Login program read the split username and password accurately but can’t figure out how which is why I came here for advice on how to fix the while, for, and if statements. Before I coded the username and password to be a single line with a separator, I could not get the login program to properly read the two lines in the text file.

Comment: I thank you both for your input. I’ve been able to solve the issue which now allows the Login program to function appropriately.